# How can I append a script field to a result?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to append a script field to a elasticsearch result. But I can't find a working solution.

I have a script field like this:

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "distance": {
      "script": "doc[my_field_name].arcDistance(my_lat, my_lon)",
      "params": {
        "my_field_name": "geopoint",
        "my_lat": 52.5,
        "my_lon": 13.4
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As result I get something like that:

```
"hits": [
    {
        "fields": {
           "distance": [
              0
           ]
        }
    },
    {
        "fields": {
           "distance": [
              500
           ]
        }
    },
    {
        "fields": {
           "distance": [
              1000
           ]
        }
    }
]
```

But I need full documents together with the script fields. So I've tried this:

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "distance": {
      "script": "doc[my_field_name].arcDistance(my_lat, my_lon)",
      "params": {
        "my_field_name": "geopoint",
        "my_lat": 52.5,
        "my_lon": 13.4
      }
    },
    "source": {
      "script": "_source"
    }
  }
}
```

But as result I get something like this:

```
"hits": [
    {
        "fields": {
            "distance": [
                0
            ],
            "source": [
                {
                    "id": "101",
                    "geopoint": {
                        "lon": 52.5,
                        "lat": 13.4
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "distance": [
                500
            ],
            "source": [
                {
                    "id": "101",
                    "geopoint": {
                        "lon": 52.5,
                        "lat": 13.4
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "distance": [
                1000
            ],
            "source": [
                {
                    "id": "101",
                    "geopoint": {
                        "lon": 52.5,
                        "lat": 13.4
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

The source is in this case the same for all hits. I have thought the `_source` loads per document, but doesn't look so.

How can I achieve script field together with the document as result or isn't this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on the wrong track. The solutions was to change the request to:

```
{
  "fields": [
    "_source"
  ],
  "script_fields": {
    "distance": {
      "script": "doc[my_field_name].arcDistance(my_lat, my_lon)",
      "params": {
        "my_field_name": "geopoint",
        "my_lat": 52.5,
        "my_lon": 13.4
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the result looks than something like this:

```
"hits": [
    {
        "fields": {
            "distance": [
                0
            ],
        },
        "_source": {
            {
                "id": "101",
                "geopoint": {
                    "lat": 52.5,
                    "lon": 13.4
                },
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "distance": [
                500
            ],
        },
        "_source": {
            {
                "id": "102",
                "geopoint": {
                    "lat": 52.5,
                    "lon": 13.40739378
                },
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "distance": [
                1000
            ],
        },
        "_source": {
            {
                "id": "103",
                "geopoint": {
                    "lat": 52.5,
                    "lon": 13.4147875
                },
            }
        }
    }
]
```